# Can't open connection to remote database

Tags: php, mysql

I have php script running on XAMPP on my local PC and I want to access some databse other than one on my localhost. Even if I call script with my own IP address I can't connect to the database.

PHP script looks like:

```
<?php

$host = $_GET['host'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
$database = $_GET['database'];

$con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$pass);
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("performance_schema", $con);
$zavrsni = "zavrsni";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `OBJECT_NAME`,`COUNT_INSERT`,`AVG_TIMER_INSERT`,`COUNT_UPDATE`,`AVG_TIMER_UPDATE`,`COUNT_DELETE`,`AVG_TIMER_DELETE` FROM `table_io_waits_summary_by_table` where `OBJECT_SCHEMA` =\"".$database."\"");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$output[]=$row;
}

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);


?>
```

I call this script as:

```
http://zavrsni.noip.me/dohvat.php?username=root&pass=ficko1&database=zavrsni&host=zavrsni.noip.me
```

And then I get error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\dohvat.php on line 8
Could not connect: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

I know that this is not the most secure way of connecting the database, but I'm new to PHP so don't judge the terrible code.

Comment: Everything is in error message

Comment: Your hostname may be wrong

Comment: sorry, but I don't unserstand what to do, that's why I asked question here

Comment: Try to connect from the mysql command line interface. What error message do you get?

Comment: hostname is the right one because it's the same as one I have my apache server on

Comment: @AlexMonthy this is what i get while connecting via cmd: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'zavrsni.noip.me' (10060)

Comment: there is no open mysql port on your ip http://pastebin.com/kfkJPWBY make sure Mysql in ON, port is open to world (check firewall), and remote access is granted. As @Kasyx said, everything is in error message...

Comment: From your PHP script, try to connect to host 127.0.0.1 - does that work? So that the URL would read "...&host=127.0.0.1"

Comment: @AlexMonthy yeah it works if I try to connect via host=localhost or host=127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database is not open for connections from outside. 
Log in to the server on which the database resides, log in to your database as root and then enter:

```
USE zavrsni;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * to root@% identified by 'ficko1';
```

or better

```
GRANT SELECT ON * to root@% identified by 'ficko1';
```

Please note that it global grants are highly unsure. Learn how to use the privilege system and later grant only those privileges which are actually needed.

If this still does not work, your mysql server is not permitting connections from outside. Have a look at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html